# How to handle complex, inter-connected flows in JSF?

Tags: jsf, cdi, jsf-2.2, java-ee-7

What if my application has flows like A->B->C->A where A should be a newly scoped instance when coming from A, but should nicely go back using the right scope while using the back button?

I'd like to solve this in a standard way if possible. Custom CDI scopes are ok if needed. Third party libraries too if it can't be done in a standard way and the use case is generic enough. I'll also favor pure Java, type-safe solutions.

edit: for example, consider those views :

- invoice list (all customers or search)
- invoice details
- customer list
- customer details

There are 2 obvious flows : master -> details and back for invoices and customers.

You could also follow a link from an invoice in the list to its customer's details. This last page displays a list of invoices in a tab, by the way. After editing the customer, you should be able to go back to the invoice list.

I've one managed bean for both invoice list/details, and one for customer list/details, but I could consider splitting it if this helps solving.

Comment: Can you give a more concrete example of what you're trying to do?  I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: Just edited my question with an example. Is this clearer?

Comment: Why dont you go for 4 session-scoped managed beans ?

Comment: Why not splitting in 4 managed beans, but I want the first A and the second one in A->B->C->A to be different instances. That excludes session scope. Or, regarding my example, I'd like to open multiple customer details simultaneously.

Comment: @ViewAccessScoped of CDI may serve your purpose :) Can you have a Try on it .

Comment: @ymajoros This is where the ViewAccessScope comes in. It’s a scope defined in MyFaces CODI (a CDI extension). The ViewAccessScope is like a long-lived conversation, where the conversation ends as soon as you use a view that does not reference the ViewAccessScoped bean.

Comment: Your question is both easy and difficult to answer because while JSF can handily sort you out, you're not presenting a concrete use case. Why are you assuming separate beans are necessary for each presentation? There are a myriad of ways to present master-detail views, all without full-page refreshes (removing the need for a back button scenario). Your "flows" could very easily be presented as a popups on a single page

Comment: @KrsnaChaitanya use session scope for the data that must be stored in session only. A request to a list of something doesn't need to be in session. The data of user logged in the application does require to be in session (or not, depending on further requirements).

Comment: I need something that will work while going back from the last A to the first in A > B > C > A with the back button.

Comment: @kolossus could be a popup, could be a new page, and I don't insist on using a single or multiple beans. I just want different instances, and being able to have multiple details in multiple tabs.